# angular directive, two-way data binding with boolean works only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

trying to test a simple directive that will run if passed value is true but it works only once.

directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
               triggerObj: '@myDirective'
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('triggerObj', function() {
                    alert('success')
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

controller:

```
$scope.triggerObj = {};
$scope.triggerObj.trigger = false;

$scope.passValue = function(){
    //set to true
    $scope.triggerObj.trigger = true;
}
```

view:

```
<div my-directive='{[triggerObj.trigger]}'>
<button type='button' ng-click='passValue()'>click</button>
```

also tried to reset value to false before setting to true but still it works only once.

Comment: your triggerObj is not two way binding try instead of @triggerObj with =triggerObj

Comment: tried that in which case brackets needs to be removed from a view but the results remains the same

Answer (score 1):

It works only ones, because `passValue()` function set `$scope.triggerObj.trigger` to `true`. And your `$watch` is working only when old value is not equal to new value, but you first change `$scope.triggerObj.trigger` from `false` to `true`, and all other times nothings change (you just trying to change `$scope.triggerObj.trigger` from `true` to `true` again).

To do the trick, try to upgrade the `$scope.passValue` function to this:

```
$scope.passValue = function() {
  if($scope.triggerObj.trigger) {
    $scope.triggerObj.trigger = false;
  } else {
    $scope.triggerObj.trigger = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to put $scope.triggerObj.trigger = false; before $scope.triggerObj.trigger = true; in the function but it does not work

Comment: @user1751287, because `$scope.triggerObj.trigger = false` works only ones, on controller load. Try to upgrade the `$scope.passValue` function as I wrote in my answer, this should help.

Comment: I put it within a function as well but still does not work...see edited answer

Comment: same result with your function as well

Answer (score 1):

It works when you change passValue function like
http://jsfiddle.net/yjjysdzw/

```
  $scope.passValue = function() {
    $scope.triggerObj.trigger = !$scope.triggerObj.trigger;
  }
```

Comment: this works but I need directive to run only on true so if I pass true after your command I get the same result so it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Two way data binding is achieved with '=', not '@'.

```
scope: {
  triggerObj: '=myDirective'
}
```